# Hanging exercise equipment on cinderblock wall

Tags: garage, drill, hanging, support, cinderblock

I live in a townhouse and am separated from my neighbors by a cinderblock wall. In my garage it is pretty exposed.
I would like to hang a kayak, punching bag and pull up bar off of the wall.
Kayak will weight about 70 pounds (plus 10 pound for the hangers). Punching bag will weight 100 pounds (plus 15 pounds for the hanger). Pull up bar will weight 15 pounds plus it needs to be able to hold my 250 pound body that will be spasming out on it trying to perform a pull up (so I am guessing that might generate about 550 pounds of force).
Can I, and if so how would I go about hanging each of the three items listed above?

The heavy bag hanger will be this: https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B011UF54RW
Pull up bar will be similar.

I already hanged kayak and it seems to hold.

My biggest fear is cinderblock wall collapsing since I heard that cinderblock can't handle anything being drilled on it. It is supporting second floor and I don't want the wall collapsing.

EDIT: added pictures and more description

[image: my wall]

Comment: So it sounds like you have a *heavy bag* type puncher; don't you want it away from the wall so it has a bit of room to swing? Like, hanging from the ceiling? Can you post pics of the mounting arrangements for the items (e.g.the frame that holds the pull-up bar)? Also, maybe trivial but to directly lift 250 lbs you need to exert 250 lbs of force, so you are looking at at least 515 lbs...

Comment: @Jimmy Fix-it I have added your suggestions. And I want to hang punching bag near wall so that when I need to park the car it's not going to require me to remove it. I am ok with heavy bag rubbing against the wall. Most of time it's my hands that break the bag instead of the wall :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your information I would have to go with toggle bolts.
C-90 Hollow Block (1 1/2-inch wall)
An anchor sized at 1/8 inches can take 310 pounds, at 3/16 inches it can take 700 pounds, and a 1/4-inch anchor in a 1 1/2-inch thick wall can take 1,390 pounds. This increases to a whopping 3,620 pounds for a 1/2-inch anchor with a 1 1/4-inch embedded depth.
Good luck with those pull ups.